# Open current file in external editor

Tags: ide, matlab

For all it's shortcomings, I usually prefer to work inside the Matlab IDE, rather than in an external editor (due to ease of debugging, running and so on).

However sometimes I want to open the current file in an external text editor. I can do: r-click file tab; show in Finder; open file in editor, but that is really too much for most occasions.

What I want is to assign an external editor that could be launched with the currently selected file.

Is there a built-in way to accomplish this?

If not, is the Matlab IDE itself scriptable, so I could write a script that could then be assigned a shortcut?

(discalimer: I have googled - didn't find anything)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Vincent for putting me on to `system`. My solution is mostly for me (so no fancyness), but feel free to adapt to your editor of choice.

**Edit:** Note that this solution incorporates undocumented functionality. If I recall correctly, `matlab.desktop.editor.getActive().Filename;` works from about 2009 and at least works in 2013a on OSX

```
function subl(varargin)
% Opens the currently active tab of the matlab editor in sublime text
% (assuming OSX, and that subl is found on the system $PATH).
% Adam Andersen Læssøe; Feb. 2014.
%
% Input: 
%    varagin{1} (if supplied) is passed directly to the subl call as a string 
%    for a list of args see eg. www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html
% Result: 
%    (). subl is called with the args followed by the path to the currently
%    active file in the matlab editor. 
% Example usage: (opens the currently active editor tab in sublime text in
%                 a new window)
%    subl -n

file = matlab.desktop.editor.getActive().Filename;
if nargin 
    args = varargin{1};
else 
    args = '';
end
%args = '';
system(['subl ', args, ' ', file]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could open the file from matlab with the macopen function (or if you are on windows: winopen):

```
function macopen(file)
% Opens a file or directory, as if executing at the Terminal
% Manu Raghavan
% August 19, 2009

if(nargin==0 || nargin>1 || ~ischar(file))
    error('Please specify at one input argument, file or directory, to be opened');
end

if(~ismac)
    if(ispc)
        error('macopen does not work on Windows, use winopen instead');
    else
        error('macopen does not work on other operating systems');
    end
end

system(['open ',file]);
```

source: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25080-macopen/content/macopen.m
author: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/31269

Comment: Thank you Vincent, but that would require me to type out the whole filename. Thank you for the macopen, though. That could be part of a viable solution.
Is there a command to get the (file of the) currently active tab?
That could be easily combined with macopen in, say, `exto`.

Comment: Not that easy to find, but here it is (gets full path): `matlab.desktop.editor.getActive().Filename`

Answer (score 0):

You could run a editor in the operating system from the matlab command line.

Something like

```
     !emacs filename.m
```

Comment: The filename should autocomplete.